# In R I want to add everything after an underscore to a string in a previous row so that they each have the same string after said underscore

Tags: r, string, character

Say I have a column that has the following;

```
c("Q9NZ", "Q69Z_1036_1037_1_1_S1036", "A3K8", "P123_567_789_1_1_T567")
```

I want the output to find the underscore in the row beneath it and copy that plus the remainder of the string to the row that I am working with.
Desired output is;

```
c("Q9NZ_1036_1037_1_1_S1036" , "Q69Z_1036_1037_1_1_S1036" , "A3K8_567_789_1_1_T567" ,"P123_567_789_1_1_T567")
```

Comment: So you only want to do that for rows that don't already have an underscore?

Comment: Yes that is correct, those rows do not have an underscore.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! This helped me out immensely, would upvote you all if I could.

Comment: Even though your rep is too low to upvote, you can still accept an answer. As far as I can tell you have not accepted any of the answers to your prior questions.

Comment: Thanks, I chose Mr. Flick and here's why. Even though Gregor's solution works perfectly for this exact question (and thank you), Mr. Flick takes into account if the next string isn't until more than 1 row down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dplyr+tidyr method

```
data.frame(x) %>% 
  tidyr::separate_wider_delim(x, delim="_", names = c("prefix", "suffix"), too_many = "merge", too_few="align_start") %>% 
  tidyr::fill(suffix, .direction="up") %>% 
  transmute(value=paste(prefix, suffix, sep="_"))
```

which returns

```
  value                   
  <chr>                   
1 Q9NZ_1036_1037_1_1_S1036
2 Q69Z_1036_1037_1_1_S1036
3 A3K8_567_789_1_1_T567   
4 P123_567_789_1_1_T567
```

so if you need the data in a data.frame, this might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = c("Q9NZ", "Q69Z_1036_1037_1_1_S1036", "A3K8", "P123_567_789_1_1_T567")

## identify target items without underscores
target_rows = grep(pattern = "_", x, invert = TRUE)

## remove everything up to the first underscore in the following rows
next_row_after_underscore = sub(pattern = "[^_]*_", replacement = "_", x[target_rows + 1])

## paste together
x[target_rows] = paste0(x[target_rows], next_row_after_underscore)
x
# [1] "Q9NZ_1036_1037_1_1_S1036" "Q69Z_1036_1037_1_1_S1036" "A3K8_567_789_1_1_T567"   
# [4] "P123_567_789_1_1_T567"
```